# Regex to remove data between 2 semicolns perl

Tags: perl

A string have data with semicolons now i want to remove all the data within the 2 semicolons and leave the rest as it is. I am using perl regex to remove the unwanted data from the string:

String :

```
$val="Data;test is here ;&data=1dffvdviofv;&dt&;&data=343";
```

Now we want to remove all the data between each semicolons ,throughout the string :

```
$val=~s/(.*)(\;.*\;)(.*)$/$1$3/g;
```

But this is not working for me. Final out should be like below :

```
Data &data=1dffvdviofv&data=343
```

Comment: Try this: `$val =~ s/([^;]*);[^;]*;/$1/g;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the problems is that `.*` is greedy, that is, it will consume as much as it can. You can make it non-greedy by writing `.*?`, but that alone won't fix your regex since you've anchored it to the end of the string with `$`. Personally I don't think there is a need for the capture groups, you can just write

```
$val =~ s/;.*?;//g;
```

I'm assuming that the extra space in your expected output (`Data &data...`) is a typo.

You might also want to consider using a proper parser for whatever data format this is.

Comment: Safer: `;[^;]*;`